# How can I calculate a weighted moving average concentration for each chemical over years at a particular location?

Tags: r, moving-average

I'm attempting to calculate a weighted moving average for each analyte_station. I have attempted this a number of ways in R but keep getting NA return values and I can't figure out why.

The moving average will be calculated from the previous 5 years of data (not including the current year) for each analyte_station. The weight will be the number of samples or "Count" column.

So each "ANALYTE_STATION" will have it's own weighted mean value for each year.

The error I keep getting is: Column `Mean.5` must be length 1 (the group size), not 35320

OR, the function will return NA values for the entire column

I'm new to R and have tried using zoo and deplyr libraries and lag, mutate, and rollapply functions.

A common error I keep getting is: Column `Mean.5` must be length 1 (the group size), not 35320

OR, the function will return NA values for the entire column.

```
dput(head(mean2))
structure(list(
YEAR_ANALYTE_STATION = c("2006 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"2007 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2008 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2009 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"2010 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2013 4,4'-DDD CCE-01"), 
Year = c(2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2013L), 
CCEMean = c(1.96969696966667, 
0.635237880333333, 10.108880584, 8.91217270166667, 18.54267311, 
1.409054917), Count = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), 
ANALYTE_STATION = 
c("4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE- 
01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = 
c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
vars = "ANALYTE_STATION", 
drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, 
labels = structure(list(ANALYTE_STATION = "4,4'-DDD CCE-01"), row.names = 
c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "ANALYTE_STATION", drop = TRUE))

head(mean2)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ANALYTE_STATION [1]
YEAR_ANALYTE_STATION  Year CCEMean Count ANALYTE_STATION
<chr>                <int>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>          
1 2006 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2006   1.97  3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
2 2007 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2007   0.635 3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
3 2008 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2008  10.1   3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
4 2009 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2009   8.91  3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
5 2010 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2010  18.5   3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
6 2013 4,4'-DDD CCE-01  2013   1.41  3     4,4'-DDD CCE-01
```

I am able to get the following code to work, but now I would like to add a weight to the rolling mean.

## moving mean for the previous years not including the current year (e.g. 5 represents the mean of the 5 previous years)

```
mean5 = mean %>%
  mutate(Mean.lag1 = lag(Mean, n = 1)) %>%
  mutate(Mean.5.previous = rollapply(data = Mean.lag1, 
                                 width = 5, 
                                 FUN = mean, 
                                 align = "right", 
                                 fill = NA, 
                                 na.rm = T))
```

Ultimately, each "ANALYTE_STATION" will have it's own weighted mean (from the 5 previous years) value for each year.

Comment: Could you provide your data with the output of `dput(head(mean2))` rather than like just the `head()` output? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My question has been edited. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: How do you define "5 previous years"? 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010 or 2008, 2009, 2010, since 2013 - 5 = 2008?

Comment: So I defined it as the last 5 years of available data. I read that the rollmean function calculates using the number of lines. On another note, I was able to get these functions to work. Now I am trying to add the weighted portion of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function, that calculates rather the mean of the last 5  years than that of rows.

```
myRollmean <- function(x, tm, rge, excl.last=0) sapply(1:length(x), function(i) {
  period <- (tm[i] - rge - excl.last):(tm[i] - excl.last)
  return(mean(x[which(tm %in% period)]))
})
```

`x` denotes the column which mean we are interested in. `tm` is the time column, `rge` the time range, i.e. 5 years in your case, `excl.last` denotes how much years should be excluded.

```
df1$Mean.5 <- myRollmean(df1$CCEMean, df1$Year, 5)
df1$Mean.5.previous <- myRollmean(df1$CCEMean, df1$Year, 5, 1)
```

**Result**

```
> df1
  YEAR_ANALYTE_STATION Year    CCEMean Count ANALYTE_STATION   Mean.5 Mean.5.previous
1 2006 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2006  1.9696970     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 1.969697             NaN
2 2007 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2007  0.6352379     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 1.302467        1.969697
3 2008 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2008 10.1088806     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 4.237938        1.302467
4 2009 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2009  8.9121727     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 5.406497        4.237938
5 2010 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2010 18.5426731     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 8.033732        5.406497
6 2013 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 2013  1.4090549     3 4,4'-DDD CCE-01 9.743195        9.549741
```

Could you please check whether the function yields the desired result?

**Data**

```
mean2 <- structure(list(YEAR_ANALYTE_STATION = c("2006 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"2007 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2008 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2009 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"2010 4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "2013 4,4'-DDD CCE-01"), Year = c(2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2013L), CCEMean = c(1.96969696966667, 
0.635237880333333, 10.108880584, 8.91217270166667, 18.54267311, 
1.409054917), Count = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), ANALYTE_STATION = c("4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", "4,4'-DDD CCE-01", 
"4,4'-DDD CCE-01")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "ANALYTE_STATION", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:5), group_sizes = 6L, biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    ANALYTE_STATION = "4,4'-DDD CCE-01"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = "data.frame", vars = "ANALYTE_STATION", drop = TRUE))

df1 <- as.data.frame(mean2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did  not work for me. Your numbers look correct, but my numbers are very high and clearly incorrect. I must be doing something wrong. i was able to get my original code to work and have edited it in the question. I am now trying to add the weight factor (count column) to my rolling weighted mean. Thank you for all your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question states that the code near the end of the question gives the desired unweighted answer it seems that what is wanted is the mean of the prior 5 rows of the data frame.  Actually that code cannot be correct as of the 6 means it produces all should be NA except the last because only thr last row has 5 prior rows; however, in fact that code gives a non-NA value for the 5th row which is incorrect -- it should be NA since there are only 4 rows prior to the 5th, not 5.

To fix that try the following code.  Note from `?rollapply` that the `width` argument can be a one element list of offsets so `list(-seq(5))` means the previous 5 elements and also note that `rollapplyr` with an r on the end can be used instead of `align="right"`.  In the data shown in the question there are no NAs in the `CCEMean` column and  if that is the case we don't need the `na.rm` argument although it won't hurt.

```
mean2 %>%
  mutate(Mean5prev = rollapplyr(CCEMean, list(-seq(5)), mean, fill = NA, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The question did not precisely define what weights to use but it would just be a matter of replacing `mean` in the above with a function that calculates the weighted mean in whatever manner you want.  Try using the `weighted.mean` function appropriately for that.